How to share the standard input with a child process in Python?
I need to do in Python what this C++ program does:
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    char buffer[256];

    read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    std::cout << "(1) Parent received: " << buffer << std::endl;

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) { // Child process
        // Read from the pipe (parent's input)
        read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        std::cout << "(2) Child received: " << buffer << std::endl;

        return 0; // Child process finished
    } else { // Parent process
        wait(NULL); // Wait for the child to finish
    }

    printf("done with child\n");

    read(0, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    std::cout << "(3) Parent received: " << buffer << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

This program is first reading from its standard input, then it forks a child process which re-uses parent's stdin and reads from this stdin, and then the parent process waits for the child to finish, and it keeps reading data from the same stdin handle.
How can the same be done in Python?
I've read the documentation of the subprocess.Popen() function but I couldn't find how to share stdin between parent and child processes.

This is a feature of the operating system, not primarily of the language; but Python implements some language-level buffering etc on the stdin file handle, so you need to take some extra precautions. I'll mark this as a duplicate of a question of my own with a similar answer.

I haven't tried sharing back and forth like that, but to let the subprocess.Popen() process use the parent process's stdin, just set stdin=sys.stdin as an argument in the Popen call.  I would think that both processes could continue to use this stream, but you would need to be careful to avoid simultaneous reading which would cause race conditions.

Of course, the direct correlation where the child process code is in the same source would be to use python's os.fork().
